# WiFi is painfully slow, sometimes stops altogether

Tags: wireless, 12.10, internet

Lately my WiFi connection has been quite slow, and sometimes I lose my internet connection altogether (but the computer does not actually disconnect from the WiFi network). This only affects my laptop and only when it's running Ubuntu, so I think it must be a problem with Ubuntu. I haven't changed anything recently; this is on 12.10 64-bit. What could it be?

Update: It's doing this now. The connection isn't completely dead, it's just staying under 5 kB/s. Still frustrating though. It also seems to affect all users.

Update 2: Output from `sudo lspci --n`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 [8086:1c1e] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c4b] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [8086:008a] (rev 34)
0b:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
```

It's not happening right now; it seems to start & stop at random. Also, I've had Ubuntu on this computer and used this network for a while now. I don't think it's a driver issue, although I'm not sure what else it could be.

Update 3: I disabled IPv6 as Alex suggested, and it's worked ever since. That may have solved it; I'll wait and see if it keeps working for the rest of the day.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Network menu and click on the "Connection Information" menu. If there's nothing under the IPv6 box, you can safely [disable IPv6](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/disable-ipv6-if-your-internet-is.html). Also, it would be useful if you could compare the connection speed (located under the "General" box) between Windows (or any other OS you have installed) and Ubuntu. 
If you use a Wireless N device, you should install the wlan-ng drivers (you can search them in the Software Center).

Finally, you can try resetting your modem and/or your router. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Disconnect your modem from the power source.
2. Wait 15 seconds.
3. Connect your modem again
4. Wait for it to boot, it may take a while.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the right driver. Sometimes you need a proprietary extra driver to get it to work properly. More information on the laptop and network card would be helpful in finding what the solution is.

Comment: I doubt it's the drivers. I've had this computer (and Ubuntu) since about February and I haven't had any real problems until now. The problems only started a few days ago, and I don't think I had installed anything weird or changed any system settings around that time.